# Is there a way to get a list of keyboard keys and their respective keycodes without hardcoding it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard, frontend, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a drop down list with keyboard keys as the options but I don't want to hardcode all of the keys and their codes.

Answer (score 0):

Based on w3schools docs [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_keyboardevent.asp) I think you'll have to hardcode it.
Why don't you just listen to a keyboard input from the user and save its value instead of the dropdown?

Comment: That's a good point, however I want the user to see a list of key options to choose from.

Comment: @JacobFinamore So you'll have to hardcode them, sorry!